# Registering structuremap with open generic types result in error

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3, open-generics

**Open Generic Type**

```
public interface ICrudRepository<TEntity, in TKey> where TEntity : class, new()
{
```

**Implementation**

```
public class EmployeeRepository:ICrudRepository<Employee,int>
{
```

**Registration**

```
private static void OnRegistry(ConfigurationExpression iocLib)
        {
            iocLib.Scan(scanner =>
            {
                //bind interfaces with their implementations
                scanner.WithDefaultConventions();

                //scan for types from below projects
                scanner.IncludeNamespace("MyApp.Repository");
                scanner.IncludeNamespace("MyApp.Data");                

                //bind to repository base
                scanner.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ICrudRepository<,>));

                //bind crudrepository interface with the class that implements it
                scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ICrudRepository<,>));
            });
```

**Usage**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICrudRepository<Employee, int> _employeeRepository;

        public HomeController(ICrudRepository<Employee, int> employeeRepository)
        {
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }
```

**Problem:**

Interface `ICrudRepository` is inside the project MyApp.Repository and the implementation is within the project MyApp.Data. I am greeted with a exception as below on invoking the HomeController. Have no clues as to what is wrong ?

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically
>   determined for type ICrudRepository`<`Employee, Int32`>` There is no
>   configuration specified for ICrudRepository`<`Employee, Int32`>`

Here is dump of What Do i have ?

```
===================================================================================================
PluginType           Namespace        Lifecycle     Description                           Name     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Func<TResult>        System           Transient     Open Generic Template for Func<>      (Default)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Func<T, TResult>     System           Transient     Open Generic Template for Func<,>     (Default)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IContainer           StructureMap     Transient     Object:  StructureMap.Container       (Default)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Lazy<T>              System           Transient     Open Generic Template for Func<>      (Default)
===================================================================================================
```

Comment: Try add `scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof(ICrudRepository<,>));` to your `OnRegistry()` method.

Comment: @Masoud Nope did not work `No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'ICrudRepository<Employee, Int32>`